# invoking 'this' function within $on listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, this, listener

How to correctly Invoke this function within listener (which 'this' reference to window scope)?

```
this.openPackage = function (package) {
...
}

$rootScope.$on('open_Package', function (event, package) {
           openPackage(package); // doesn't work
});
```

Comment: What "_doesn't work_" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an arrow func to stay in context:

```
 $rootScope.$on('open_Package',  (event, package) => {
       this.openPackage(package); // does work
 });
```

Comment: absolutly right bro !! just for knowing, is there another solutions? (mabye by call or apply ?)

Comment: @tom you could `bind` the context or pass it or..